# Gradle build-script file dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, intershop

As a complete gradle noob I have a little problem with finding the right way to integrate a dependency into my build process.

As I am not a 100% familiar with the correct gradle terms i am going to use the framework-specific terms with an description.
Environment: Gradle-Wrapper (2.11)
InterShop-System with multiple Cartridge-Sets (publishable projects) with several Cartridges (publishable subprojects -> each cartridge creates its individuell output result, which usually is a jar file and a zip file).

```
Cartridge-Set-A
    Cartridge-a1
    Cartridge-a2
    ...
Cartridge-Set-B
    Cartrige-b1
    Cartrige-b2
...
```

Normal java or project dependencies are no problem.
I have a gradle scripts which i want to use in the build.gradle of several different cartridges e.g. a1,b1,d4.

My idea was to somehow publish my scripts to the nexus-repository which would allow my to specify the scripts as an dependency. -> Problem i have no idea how to setup a gradlew-project that doesn't have any java code inside and isn't based on of the intershop plugins. There are intershop plugins to use for static content (templates,js, etc.) only, but these dependencies get automatically deployed which isn't necessary in my case as the dependency is only required during the build process.

Short Version:
I want to be able to call the following line

```
apply from: 'path/to/file/subscript.gradle'
```

in my build.gradle in several projects without having a copy in each project.
Whats the best way to do this.

Comment: To add to the anwser about writing your own plugin.
Here is an example of a code generator plugin. 
https://github.com/willemevertse/ICM-Code-Generator-Plugin

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have some generalized functionality that is common to many different builds.  In that case, it makes sense to write a plug-in that implements that functionality and then apply the plugin to the build.gradle files that you want to use it on:

```
class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('hello') {
            doLast {
                println 'Hello from the GreetingPlugin'
            }
        }
    }
}

// Apply the plugin
apply plugin: GreetingPlugin
```

Output:

```
> gradle -q hello
Hello from the GreetingPlugin
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:writing_a_simple_plugin

Otherwise, you would need to setup a multi-project build and have a closure or task in `allProjects` with the common functionality

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html